# How can I sort a list of items from Firestore consumed with a FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a list of items with a "paidStatus" field attached to it.
I get the list from Firestore with a FutureBuilder and a listview.builder.
How can I sort the list to show paid items only or unpaid items only?

```
class PreviousCarts extends StatefulWidget {
  const PreviousCarts({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PreviousCartsState createState() => _PreviousCartsState();
}

class _PreviousCartsState extends State<PreviousCarts> {
  final style = GoogleFonts.volkhov(fontSize: 18);

  Future<QuerySnapshot> documentIds;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    documentIds = FirestoreAPI.documentsList(currentUser);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomerAppBar(page: 3, size: size),
      body: Column(  // first row is for the sort text and icon. should show menu options for paid and unpaid
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                    child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.sort, color: Colors.purple),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Text('sort by', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple)),
                  ],
                ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 14,
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: documentIds,
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

                  default:
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      try {
                        List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = snapshot.data.documents;
                        final finalList = sortedSnapshots(docs);

                        return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: finalList.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            
                            final documentId = finalList[index].documentID;
                            final total = finalList[index].data["total"];
                            final paidStatus = finalList[index].data["paidStatus"];


                            return Card(
                              child: ListTile(
                                leading: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 8.0, right: 25),
                                  child: Text(documentId, style: style),
                                ),
                                title: Text('$total dhs',
                                    style: style.copyWith(fontSize: 15)),
                                trailing: Container(
                                  width: 60,
                                  height: 20,
                                  child: Text(paidStatus ? "Paid" : "Unpaid",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: style.copyWith(
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          color: paidStatus
                                              ? Colors.lightBlue
                                              : Colors.red[400])),
                                ),
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                                    PageTransition(
                                        type: PageTransitionType.transferRight,
                                        child: FirestoreCart(documentId)),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      } on FormatException catch (e) {
                        return formatExceptionDialog(context, e.toString());
                      } catch (e) {
                        return uknownErrorDialog(context, e.toString());
                      }
                    } else {
                      return uknownErrorDialog(context, snapshot.error);
                    }
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: One possibility I thought of is to keep a list of bools for each item outside the build method. But that idea evaporated quickly once I realized that the list items have already been consumed and I can't mess them anymore.

I think that this can be done by storing the items first instead of immediately consuming and building a widget. But I don't feel that's an advisable way to deal with Firestore requests.

---

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried modified this `FirestoreAPI.documentsList(currentUser)` to ask Firestore to order the item for you?

```
Firestore.instance.collection('items').orderBy('paidStatus')
```